# Connecting to database server in c# securely

Tags: c#, php, wpf

Through research i cant seem to find the best approach, I am making a WPF application and want all users to connect to my database server.

However I don't wish to have the connection details (IP Address, database password) stored on the application. i am currently playing around with PHP as the bridge between.

I have a database server on a domain. I am connecting through `HttpClient` and getting a response via a JSON file. However i am concerned as the file can be accessed from anywhere. for example my url is `www.domian.co.uk/scores.php`. to increase security i have add a parameter in the `StringContent` which will only work if this is set. Could i also use `.htaccess` to prevent the file being seen or would this have an effect on my `HttpClient`.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));
```

**option 2**
An alternative i have been looking into but have test due to pricing is [Windows Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/mobile/?v=17.23h). I believe this would be a good alternative as alot of the backend work has been done for me. From this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet), you can get the Connection String for your azure service and use `System.Data.SqlClient` to make database queries. However the Connection string still requires your password to be included, is this secure including the password or do i need to create a separate DB user with strict permissions?

**option 3** From research another option would be to use WCF.

Comment: You should not do this - it is inherently insecure as your client application would need to load the connection string and connect to your database. You should rather create a web service between your WPF application and your database (host this in IIS). You would then connect to that service using WCF.

Comment: @JoaoLourenco Okay, i have created php scripts but that data is accessible to anyone when the page is opened, any tutorials or pointers as cant find a clear explanation or if you have a good explanation.

Comment: Basically you want the brains of your application to be on your server, with the WPF application accessing data through services that you expose. Hosting a WCF service in IIS is the best way from a Windows perspective as it provides security out of the box. This topic is really so big that it can't be explained here. I suggest googling "Service Oriented Architecture WCF IIS" to find a decent tutorial.

Comment: @joaoLourenco okay i will look into it, is the php scripts a bad approach or can a get the data from php without using echo? thought about sending an encrypted password to allow access.

Comment: Yes this is a very bad approach. Anyone who calls that php page will have clear database access, and you have to open up your database to all of the IP ranges where people will use your WPF application. Using a service oriented architecture approach will mean that your database is invisible to any external (and uncontrollable) systems.